# Are large prime numbers kept secret?

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

I've read several times that modern cryptography is based on the fact that multiplying two primes is easy, whereas getting the prime factorization of a random big integer is very hard. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography))

Does it mean that the largest prime numbers known are kept secret, for cryptography purposes ?

If they were not, one could compute the product of every pair of known prime numbers and decode the public keys ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic here. In any case it might be so at [Crypto S.E.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The number of 2048 bit primes can be roughly estimated to $2.8\times 10^{147}$ (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16091676/923955). Can you think how big a lookup table would be?

Comment: @egreg ok, I think this answers my question.

Comment: Look e.g. at RSA with two prime $p,q.\;$ You publish $n=pq$ and the encryption exponent $e$. You compute and keep the private decryption exponent $d$. The primes $p,q$ are **not** kept (and normally safely erased in computer memory after the computation is completed). But note that they can be recovered from $n$ and $d,e.$